# Изменить событие смены значения

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить. Может какое-нибудь другое событие есть. 
**Есть** комбоБокс, который при смене значения записывает мне значение в список, а после отображает в датагриде.
**Проблема** при нескольких сменах значения или если значение было изменено с какого-либо на пустое у меня в гриде отображается пустой столбец
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            comboBox3.SelectedValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                    indexAttributes.Add(comboBox3.Name);
            };
```

Comment: что за объект `indexAttributes`? Мало кода для анализа проблемы.

Comment: просто string-овый список